# Click event not working on Heads-up notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

Nothing happens on clicking `Accept` or `Reject` button of the head-ups notification.

But when the head-up notification disappear and from clicking `Accept` and `Reject` from the notification panel is working.

Testing on Android 5.1.0.

```
Intent acceptIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
acceptIntent.setAction("com.android.test.Accept");
PendingIntent acceptPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TestApplication.getAppContext(), 12345, acceptIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Intent rejectIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
rejectIntent.setAction("com.android.test.Reject");
PendingIntent rejectPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TestApplication.getAppContext(), 12345, rejectIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fundu);
builder.setContentTitle("Test Notification");
builder.setContentText("Hello");
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
builder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
builder.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE);
builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);
builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_check_icon, "Accept", acceptPendingIntent);
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_close, "Reject", rejectPendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setting the vibration, makes it working fine.

`builder.setVibrate(new long[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

The key is to call setContentIntent on the Notification Builder and passing it a PendingIntent. The Full code with comments explaining each step is included below. See the part named "THIS IS THE PERTINENT PART" (The Full code is included for completeness sake.)

```
// Use Notification Builder to start things off
// There are other ways of acquiring a Notification Builder; this is just an example
String channelId = "channelId";
String title = "title";
String body = "body";
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId);
notificationBuilder
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(body);


//--------------- THIS IS THE PERTINENT PART ---------------
// Prepare Intent for creating PendingIntent
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityToStart.class);

// Create Pending Intent
int requestCode= 1234;    // requestCode has to be a unique ID for EACH PendingIntent
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
        requestCode,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT    // use to prevent re-using current Activity Intent
);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

// Finally, create the Notification
Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
```